# Сайт не продвигается из за контекстной рекламы?

Tags: seo

Всем привет. Заметил такую закономерность, если сайт не рекламировать в контекстной рекламе, то по сео идет неплохое продвижение, а если рекламировать, то вообще, стоит мертвой точкой на 100 строчках. Поисковая система Google. Скажите, это совпадение или действительно есть такой прикол, что если запускать контекст то google его не поднимает, т.к. понимает что если поднимет сайт, потеряет контекстную рекламу?